# postgresql error when inserting a documet using express

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am making an app with Postgres and Nodejs but I get an error when inserting any doc.

Here are the table commands:

```
CREATE TABLE threads (
    _id  SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    board_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES board(_id),
    text TEXT NOT NULL,
    delete_password TEXT NOT NULL,
    reported  BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    bumped_on TIMESTAMP 
);

CREATE TABLE board (
    _id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE replies (
   _id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
   thread_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES threads(_id),
   text TEXT NOT NULL,
   delete_password TEXT NOT NULL,
   reported  BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
```

**routes**

```
const pool = require('../pg')

module.exports = function (app) {
  // _id, text, created_on(date&time), bumped_on(date&time, starts same as created_on), reported(boolean), delete_password,
  // table for every board
  function exist(exist) {
    const {_id } = exist.rows[0] 
    return  _id 
  }
    async function donotexist(name) {
      const board = await pool.query('INSERT INTO board (name) values ($1) returning  (_id)', [name])
      return board.rows[0]._id
  }

  app.route('/api/threads/:board')
    .get(async (req, res)=> {
        const name = req.params.board
        const thread_id = req.query

        // let board = await pool.query 
        // ('SELECT * FROM board WHERE name = $1', [name]);
        let thread = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM threads where _id = $1', [thread_id]);
        let {board_id} = thread.rows[0]

        let joined = 
        await pool.query('select * from board left join threads on board._id = threads.board_id where id = $1 ',[board_id])
    })
    .post(async (req, res)=> {
      try{
        const name = req.params.board;
        console.log(name)
        const { text, delete_password } = req.body;
        console.log(req.body)
        const exist = await pool.query('select * from board where name = $1', [name]);
        let board_id;

        if(exist.rows.length > 1) {
          board_id =  exist(exist)
        }
        board_id = donotexist(name)
        
        let created_on = Date.now
        let bumped_on = Date.now
        let reported = false

        const thread = 
        await pool.query(
          'INSERT INTO threads (board_id, text, delete_password, reported ,created_on, bumped_on) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING (_id)', 
           [board_id, text, delete_password, reported ,created_on, bumped_on])
        console.log(thread)
         const thread_id = thread.rows[0]._id
         res.redirect(`b/${name}/${thread_id}/`)
      }catch(e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    })
    .put((req, res)=> {
      const name = req.params.board
    })
    .delete((req, res)=> {
      const name = req.params.board
    })
    app.route('/api/replies/:name')
    .get((req, res)=> {
      const name = req.params.board
    })
    .post((req, res)=> {
      const name = req.params.board
    })
    .put((req, res)=> {
      const name = req.params.board
    })
    .delete((req, res)=> {
      const name = req.params.board
    })
}
```

The error I receive when making a post request to `/api/threads/:board`

```
{ error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "{}"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.stream.on (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  length: 169,
  name: 'error',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22P02',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file:
   'd:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\utils\\adt\\numutils.c',
  line: '259',
  routine: 'pg_strtoint32' }
popps
{ board: 'popps', text: 'we', delete_password: 'wewe' }
(node:8472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "board_name_key"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.stream.on (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
(node:8472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
{ error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "{}"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:278:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.stream.on (D:\boilerplate-project-messageboard\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  length: 169,
  name: 'error',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22P02',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file:
   'd:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\utils\\adt\\numutils.c',
  line: '259',
  routine: 'pg_strtoint32' }
```